# IIS reverse proxy to windows authenticated internal site

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, authentication, reverse-proxy

I have an internal windows authenticated website that I need to expose anonymously to external users.

extern: http://foo.com/ (public)
intern: http://privatefoo/ (requires windows auth)

I want people hitting foo.com to see no security prompt, just get access to privatefoo - I know this is possible in a simple reverse proxy setup but does anyone know how to make the proxy provide windows credentials?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Application Request Routing (ARR). http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationRequestRouting

This will do the reverse proxy using IIS7 all the way.  You can have it on the same machine or a separate machine(s).

For authentication, your best bet is to have the private site auto authenticate requests from the reverse proxy.  You can do that with a HTTP Module on the private site that runs before authentication.

I'm curious though why you would lock down a site locally that you are giving the world access to anyway?  If you're giving the world access to it, why not open it up privately too?

Comment: I have a similar configuration where the site should be available on a network of devices that only works without authentication. I want the website available locally for some users and without auth on another network (not a public network btw).

Comment: How to add auto authenticate from reverse proxy? We are using windows auth and it is not working. We get HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized.